# How to parse a String that contains XML in Java (Android)

Tags: java, android, xml, string, parsing

I have XML in the form of a String that contains:

```
<Data>
  <id>6731</id>
  <aux>82</aux>
</Data>
```

How can I get the values 6731 and 82 from the XML? The XML isn't in a document, it's simply a String.
Thanks in advance.
Actually, I tried XmlPullParser but i think that only works for xml files or URLs, not for Strings. Am I right?

Comment: type `xml parsing in android` in google?

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_xml_parsers.htm

Comment: use Xmlpull parser it is very easy just try it .....http://www.javatpoint.com/android-XMLPullParser-tutorial

Answer (score 0):

you can use three one of three libs:
DOM Parser
SAX Parser
StAX Parser

see: https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/05/parsing-xml-using-dom-sax-and-stax-parser-in-java.html

Also for Android:
https://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/xml.html